# SalesForce Marketing Cloud - SAP

Tags: marketing-cloud, sap

I want to know if i can use same IPAddress/Domain in two different acounts(instances) in same stack at same time.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Refer to this doc '[Marketing Cloud Sender Authentication Package (SAP)](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_es_sap.htm&type=5)'

> In certain scenarios, SAP can be shared across multiple accounts in the same environment. Create a support case to review your specific scenario. Reference the MIDs involved and the original SAP configuration case number in your support case.